# Request header parameters are not checked

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a spring boot application which call web services using REST :
this is an example on my call with bean configurations :

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "", response = ResultSearch.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "No data found", response = Object.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = ApiMessageResponse.HTTP_STATUS_CODE_404, response = ErrorModel.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = ApiMessageResponse.HTTP_STATUS_CODE_400, response = ErrorModel.class) })
    @GetMapping(path = "corporates", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Search for corporates")
    public Object searchCorporate(@RequestParam(name = "query") String query) throws Exception {

        return searchManagement.searchCorporates(search);

    }
```

Spring fox beans :

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {

         //Adding Header
        ParameterBuilder headerParameterBuilder = new ParameterBuilder();
        java.util.List<Parameter> headersParameters = new ArrayList<Parameter>();

        headersParameters.clear();

        headerParameterBuilder.name(Headers.TRACE_ID).description("ID of the whole trace forest").modelRef(new ModelRef("string")).parameterType("header").required(true).build();
        headersParameters.add(headerParameterBuilder.build());


        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).useDefaultResponseMessages(false).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(swaggerResourcePackage)).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfo(swaggerTitle, swaggerDescription, swaggerVersion, "", null, "", "", Collections.emptyList()))
                .protocols( new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("http","https")))
                .globalOperationParameters(headersParameters);
    }
```

When i execute the request without the header 'TRACE_ID' in Swagger Document it blocks the execution which is good but using curl command :

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8081/search/corporates?query=bddf" -H "accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

it passed without checking header authorisation/requirement !!
i'm using `springfox.version 2.8.0` and `springfoxui.version 2.9.2`
What is wrong in my config to surely verifying request header before execute request

Comment: Why do you think that someone should check for the TRACE_ID Swagger doc is only generating the documentation.

Comment: i reformulate my question : is that config (bean params) works also for checking the header require  when using curl ? or should i add header in argument function :
@RequestHeader(value="TRACE_ID ") String trace;